# Input type="number" multiples validation error messages with clr-control-error

Tags: vmware-clarity

I'm working now with **Clarity** in a personal project, I like so much this Design System, so I will stay asking a lot (sorry for that).

I was trying today to implement multiples validation message errors for a type number input into a form. Docs explains that I should use `*clr-control-error` to achieve that but it has been impossible.

At the moment validating type number input to show a "required" text works just fine.

[View post on imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSKF3.jpg)

But what about if user try to type a letter in the field? It happen with 'e' character. In that case, I want to show another text like "Invalid parameter" or something related.

[View post on imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsvXh.jpg)

I was trying do this:

```
<clr-input-container>
      <label class="clr-col-4 clr-col-md-4">Precio de Costo</label>
      <input class="clr-col-8 clr-col-md-8" clrInput type="number" formControlName="precioCosto" />
      <clr-control-error *clrIfError="'required'">Requerido</clr-control-error>
      <clr-control-error *clrIfError="'invalid'">Parámetro Inválido</clr-control-error>
 </clr-input-container>
```

But always show the first message. I was also trying to do with `*ngIf` but look like there is a conflict with `*clr-control-error`.

Did you get some way to solve this? I will very grateful with you help.

**Update:** adding Controller code to clarify issue:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-productos',
  templateUrl: './productos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./productos.component.scss']
})
export class ProductosComponent implements OnInit {

  private productoForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
     private fb: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setProductoForm();
  }

  get f() { return this.productoForm.controls; }

  setProductoForm() {
     this.productoForm = this.fb.group({
      id: [this.productos.length + 1],
      nombre: ['', Validators.required],
      laboratorio: ['', Validators.required],
      unidadMedida: ['', Validators.required],
      precioCosto: ['', Validators.required],
      precioVenta: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code where you create your form controls in the controller?

Comment: Done, @JeremyWilken.

Answer (score 0):

The letter `e` is a valid character in a number field when you use it with a digit as well, since that is a way to denote exponents. There may be inconsistencies in browsers about how they handle this but here is the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#number-state-typenumber. This is really as expected since you've not put in a required value yet, so you get `require` error type. There are other characters like `-` that might be typed in the field but still not a value by themselves.

You could write your own validator to handle these cases on your own. There is no `invalid` validator by default, you'd have to write it, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation.